# Appengine datastore raising badValueErro on datetime, might be caused by monkeypatch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, monkeypatching, pytest

I'm getting the following error message:

```
BadValueError: Expected datetime, got datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 19, 19, 48, 2, 566558)
```

The error is raised in ndb's model.py line 1190, here's a snippet of code in there.

```
def _validate(self, value):
    if not isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
        raise datastore_errors.BadValueError('Expected datetime, got %r' % (value,))
```

This DateTime is Passed into a model like this:

```
#user is a parameter that's passed into the function this code is inside
#the same goes for lifetime, which is a number of seconds

token = os.urandom(16).encode("hex")
expires=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=lifetime)
instance = cls(token=token, user=user, expires=expires)
```

However, I'm monkeypatching datetime.datetime using pytest's monkeypatch argument.

```
newnow = datetime.datetime.now()
later = newnow + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)

class fake_dt(datetime.datetime):
    @classmethod
        def now(cls):
            return newnow

monkeypatch.setattr(datetime,"datetime", fake_dt)
    #after that, I call my model creation function for the test.
```

Could the fact that I'm monkeypatching datetime.datetime be the problem? and how do I get around that? I need to make sure that datetime.datetime.now() returns the date I captured at the start of my test.